# Reading Russian in python from dta file

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am trying to read Russian characters from a .dta file and when I print to the terminal I see the following: 
`Ð¯Ð½Ð¾Ð¼Ð°Ð¼Ð¾`

That doesn't seem like Russian, so I am wondering what I have to do to get the actual Russian characters. I tried the following and it didn't work:
`ex = row['name_rus'].encode("cp1251")`

I got: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>`

Any guidance would be appreciated! I attached my script so far below in case if it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def load_large_dta(fname):
    import sys

    reader = pd.read_stata(fname, iterator=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    try:
        chunk = reader.get_chunk(100*1000)
        while len(chunk) > 0:
            df = df.append(chunk, ignore_index=True)
            chunk = reader.get_chunk(100*1000)
            print ('.')
            sys.stdout.flush()
    except (StopIteration, KeyboardInterrupt):
        pass

    print ('\nloaded {} rows'.format(len(df)))

    return df



def store_oid(df1, df2, df3):
    mapping = {}
    to_write = {}
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        russian = row['id']
        mapping[russian] = index
    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        russian_words = row['name_rus']
        russian_words = [x.strip() for x in russian_words.split(',')]
        for word in russian_words: 
            if word in mapping:
                oid = int(row['oid'])
                to_write[word] = oid
    for index, row in df3.iterrows():
        ex = row['name_rus'].encode("cp1251")
        print(ex)
def main():
    long_words = load_large_dta('russian_english_names.dta')
    single_words = load_large_dta('Ruthenia2_duplicates.dta')
    tradition_english = load_large_dta('tradition_english_russian_EA_Augu16th.dta')
    store_oid(single_words, long_words, tradition_english)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is `sys.stdout.encoding`?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? It would kinda make sense to show us which line in the script you've posted has the error.

Comment: `reader = pd.read_stata(fname, iterator=True)` you read the file with the default `latin-1` encoding. If the file was actually in cp1251, you've already mapped to the wrong unicode characters right there. You could do `reader = pd.read_stata(fname, encoding="cp1251", iterator=True)` and completely remove any other attempts at encoding. Then, if you are on a utf-8 terminal, the display should be right.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the terminal, not python. Change your terminal to use UTF-8 encoding.